# Finding the status of a recurring contribution

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

I am setting up a website using CiviContribute whereby recurring donations can be set up.  Everything seems to be working - I can see the contributions when I go to Contributions -> Find Contribution:

[image]

and in the report:

[image]

However, when I cancel the subscription in PayPal that information isn't reflected when viewing the Contribution.  The only way I can see this information is by going to Contributions -> Contribution Reports -> Recurring Contributions.

[image]

but the contribution screen doesn't change

[image]

This doesn't seem to be very intuative, so I was wondering if I had missed something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of both the Recurring Contribution on the Contribution Tab, and the same record in your report?

Comment: Added screenshots to the question

Comment: I am not sure if my Answer helps but the screenshots didn't help. I asked for shots of the Contribution Tab on the Contact record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at someones Contribution Tab (rather the Contribution itself) then down at the bottom, below the list of any Contributions, there should be rows showing any Recurring Contribution. This should show you the status of the Recurring payment.